# как дождаться окончания плавного перехода transition

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Написал вот такую вот карусель:

```
HTML
<div class="mid">
    <input class="myButton" value="◀" type="button" id="toLeft">

    <div class="carousel"><!--
       --><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/1.png" alt="A"><!--
       --><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/2.png" alt="B"><!--
       --><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/3.png" alt="C"><!--
       --><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/4.png" alt="D"><!--
       --><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/5.png" alt="E"><!--
    --></div>

    <input class="myButton down" value="▶" type="button" id="toRight">
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-duration: 0s;
}

.carousel .slow {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

JS

```
"use strict";
let leftButton = document.querySelector("#toLeft");
let rightButton = document.querySelector("#toRight");

leftButton.addEventListener("click", moveToTheLeft);
rightButton.addEventListener("click", moveToTheRight);

function moveToTheLeft() {
  let box = document.querySelector(".carousel");
  let items = document.querySelectorAll("img");

  box.append(items[0]);
}

function moveToTheRight() {
  let box = document.querySelector(".carousel");
  let items = document.querySelectorAll("img");

  for (let item of items) {
    item.style.left = "135px";
    item.classList.toggle("slow");
    setTimeout(moveFast, 310);
  }

  setTimeout(prependItem, 315);

  function moveFast() {
    for (let item of items) {
      item.style.left = "0px";
      item.classList.toggle("slow");
    }
  }

  function prependItem() {
    box.prepend(items[+items.length - 1]);
  }
}
```

Ссылка на песочницу: https://codepen.io/muturgan/pen/QQjZRG

Попробовал ее анимировать.

Сначала по ходу мысли написал:

```
for (let item of items) {
  item.style.left = "135px";
  item.classList.toggle("fast");
  item.style.left = "0px";
  item.classList.toggle("fast");
}
```

Визуального эффекта никакого не было.

Понял, что мои картинки возвращаются на место до того, как закончится transition, и задержал выполнение скрипта с помощью setTimeout, что по-моему очень неуклюже. Опять же время задержки на глаз определяется.

Есть ли какой-то более изящный способ дождаться окончания анимации?

Так же непонятен принцип изменения скорости анимации (текущий способ подобран экспериментально). По смыслу картиночки сначала должны двигаться медленно, а потом мгновенно. Так что я назначил правила:

```
img {transition-duration: 0.3s;}
.fast {transition-duration: 0s;}
```

и сначала картиночки должны были бы двигаться медленно, потом бы им присваивался класс fast, и они мгновенно перескакивали бы на исходное место. А потом класс fast убирался бы для правильного исполнения последующей итерации.

Но на практике все происходило наоборот - картинки мгновенно переносились вправо и медленно возвращались на место. Для семантичности я поменял правила CSS местами, а класс назвал slow. Но почему у картинок такое поведения, я не понял.

Comment: можно попробовать посмотреть в сторону событий, например [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend)

Answer (score 1):

1. Если хочешь анимировать самостоятельно, то используй requestAnimationFrame, а не таймауты. Тогда твоя анимация будет плавной.
2. Если ты анимируешь на js, то не анимируй этот-же элемент на css. Не используй transition.
3. Если хочешь анимировать на CSS, то манипулируй классами на js. Задавая разные классы элементам, ты будешь активировать различные transition которые ты укажешь для классов.
4. Изящно - https://greensock.com/

Что касается твоего кода, то не используй setTimeout в цикле, пока не поймешь как он работает.

Comment: ну как бы я и пошел по 3 варианту. но за советы спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Можно повесить обработчик события ontransitionend.

```
 domElement.ontransitionend = () => afterTransit();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event